# When to use pip requirements file versus install_requires in setup.py?

Tags: python, setuptools, pip, distribute, setup.py

I'm using pip with virtualenv to package and install some Python libraries.

I'd imagine what I'm doing is a pretty common scenario.  I'm the maintainer on several libraries for which I can specify the dependencies explicitly.  A few of my libraries are dependent on third party libraries that have transitive dependencies over which I have no control.

What I'm trying to achieve is for a `pip install` on one of my libraries to download/install all of its upstream dependencies.  What I'm struggling with in the pip documentation is if/how [requirements files](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#requirements-files) can do this on their own or if they're really just a supplement to using `install_requires`.

Would I use `install_requires` in all of my libraries to specify dependencies and version ranges and then only use a requirements file to resolve a conflict and/or freeze them for a production build?

Let's pretend I live in an imaginary world (I know, I know) and my upstream dependencies are straightforward and guaranteed to never conflict or break backward compatibility. Would I be compelled to use a pip requirements file at all or just let pip/setuptools/distribute install everything based on `install_requires`?

There are a lot of similar questions on here, but I couldn't find any that were as basic as when to use one or the other or using them both together harmoniously.

Comment: [This](https://caremad.io/2013/07/setup-vs-requirement/) is very nice article explaining the relationship of the two, and also how they integrate.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399534/reference-requirements-txt-for-the-install-requires-kwarg-in-setuptools-setup-py

Answer (score 76, accepted):

My philosophy is that `install_requires` should indicate a minimum of what you need.  It might include version requirements if you *know* that some versions will not work; but it shouldn't have version requirements where you aren't sure (e.g., you aren't sure if a future release of a dependency will break your library or not).

Requirements files on the other hand should indicate what you know *does* work, and may include optional dependencies that you recommend.  For example you might use SQLAlchemy but suggest MySQL, and so put MySQLdb in the requirements file).

So, in summary: `install_requires` is to keep people away from things that you know don't work, while requirements files to lead people towards things you know do work.  One reason for this is that `install_requires` requirements are *always* checked, and cannot be disabled without actually changing the package metadata.  So you can't easily try a new combination.  Requirements files are only checked at install time.

Comment: does this means you should mirror `setup.py` `install_requires=` deps in `requirements.txt`?

Comment: Having both, requirements in setup.py and a requirements file is dangerous though, because the duplication just asks to become out of sync.

Comment: Also, how do you actually work with it then? I'd assume, you use the requirements file once to get to a state that is definitely working. Then install with the actual package with pip. You'll never be able to use `-U` because that might override the dependencies from the requirements file? How do you upgrade?

Comment: Does this answer apply equally to applications and packages? Imagine my-web-app (an app) depending on some-tool (a package), both of which depend on the requests package. If some-tool has a requirements.txt file that pins a particular version or version range of requests, that would seem to create a potential problem for my-web-app, which might have specified a conflicting version/version range.

Comment: There should be only way to install a package. So having both is not recommended unless you want to confuse other contributors.

Comment: This answer is confusing. Why would I bloat my requirements.txt file with packages that are not needed?

Answer (score 27):

here's what I put in my setup.py:

```
# this grabs the requirements from requirements.txt
REQUIREMENTS = [i.strip() for i in open("requirements.txt").readlines()]

setup(
    .....
    install_requires=REQUIREMENTS
)
```

Comment: Watch out, requirements files could contain comments and inclusions. [You should use the pip parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399534/how-can-i-reference-requirements-txt-for-the-install-requires-kwarg-in-setuptool/16624700#16624700)

Comment: yes, I eventually changed this to strip out comments. pip parser looks better than my answer.

Comment: Why use a requirements file at all if all it contains is already in setup.py?

Comment: @RomainHardouin, as mentioned in comments to your linked answer, pip isn't meant to be used that way.

Comment: yeah this worked for me until a critical `--extra-index-url` in in the requirements was required and this blew up in my face. Thanks @RomainHardouin

Comment: Very cool but did not solve my problem of mixed pypi and artifactory requirements.

Comment: I cannot manage to open this file when running "python -m build", requirements.txt is not found because the script is not run directly in the current folder (and __file__ is not defined either)

Answer (score 21):

The Python Packaging User Guide has a page about this topic, I highly recommend you read it:

- [install_requires vs requirements files](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/install-requires-vs-requirements/)

#### Summary:

`install_requires` is there to list the dependencies of the package that absolutely must be installed for the package to work. It is not meant to pin the dependencies to specific versions, but ranges are accepted, for example `install_requires=['django>=1.8']`. `install_requires` is observed by `pip install name-on-pypi` and other tools.

`requirements.txt` is just a text file, that you can choose to run `pip install -r requirements.txt` against. It's meant to have versions of all dependencies and subdependencies pinned, like this: `django==1.8.1`. You can create one using `pip freeze > requirements.txt`. (Some services, like Heroku, automatically run `pip install -r requirements.txt` for you.) `pip install name-on-pypi` does not look at `requirements.txt`, only at `install_requires`.

Answer (score 8):

I only ever use a `setup.py` and `install_requires` because there is only one place to look at. It is just as powerful as having a requirements file and there is no duplication to maintain.

Comment: The question is when to use one or the other, I didn't spell it out, but my answer is saying that I always use one and never the other. How is that not answering the question?