# Reference requirements.txt for the install_requires kwarg in setuptools setup.py file

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, requirements.txt

I have a `requirements.txt` file that I'm using with Travis-CI.  It seems silly to duplicate the requirements in both `requirements.txt` and `setup.py`, so I was hoping to pass a file handle to the `install_requires` kwarg in `setuptools.setup`.

Is this possible? If so, how should I go about doing it?

Here is my `requirements.txt` file:

```
guessit>=0.5.2
tvdb_api>=1.8.2
hachoir-metadata>=1.3.3
hachoir-core>=1.3.3
hachoir-parser>=1.3.4
```

Comment: `install_requires` is used to declare dependencies on packages that are required for the package to work and are used by developer of the package, while `requirements.txt` is used to automate installing of environments, which allows installing extra software and do the version pinning and are used by sysadmins deploying the package. Their role and target audience differ significantly, so trying to combine them like OP wishes is a genuine design mistake imho.

Comment: My 2 cents. Do not use requirements.txt in your setup.py. The purposes are different, ared https://caremad.io/2013/07/setup-vs-requirement/

Comment: I see lots of complicated answers. What's wrong with plain old `[line.strip() for line in open("requirements.txt").readlines()]`?

Comment: It is not recommended to do this. But if really needed then it is straightforward: _setuptools_ itself already has everything necessary [`pkg_resources.parse_requirements()`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#requirements-parsing)

Answer (score 342, accepted):

You can flip it around and list the dependencies in `setup.py` and have a single character — a dot `.` — in `requirements.txt` instead.

---

Alternatively, even if not advised, it is still possible to parse the `requirements.txt` file (if it doesn't refer any external requirements by URL) with the following hack (tested with `pip 9.0.1`):

```
install_reqs = parse_requirements('requirements.txt', session='hack')
```

This doesn't filter [environment markers](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirement-specifiers) though.

---

In old versions of pip, more specifically [older than 6.0](https://github.com/pypa/pip/commit/7037443975ee5706ef829f14a52ac2fba7dbfff2), there is a public API that can be used to achieve this. A requirement file can contain comments (`#`) and can include some other files (`--requirement` or `-r`). Thus, if you really want to parse a `requirements.txt` you can use the pip parser:

```
from pip.req import parse_requirements

# parse_requirements() returns generator of pip.req.InstallRequirement objects
install_reqs = parse_requirements(<requirements_path>)

# reqs is a list of requirement
# e.g. ['django==1.5.1', 'mezzanine==1.4.6']
reqs = [str(ir.req) for ir in install_reqs]

setup(
    ...
    install_requires=reqs
)
```

Comment: What if the user does not have pip installed?  Ka-boom?

Comment: @GringoSuave If the user does not have pip installed, he needs to install it first.

Comment: What about git requirements?

Comment: You also need to supply the urls in your requirements file, in case there are any -e or -f ("editable" git repo) lines pointing to non-pypi packages. Use this: `setup(..., dependency_links=[str(req_line.url) for req_line in parse_requirements(<requirements_path>)], ...)`

Comment: pip is now included in Python 3.4 :)

Comment: You really don't want to do this. Speaking as a pip maintainer pip does not support being called as an API like this at all. In fact pip 1.6 (next version at this time) moves this function.

Comment: Too bad! Thanks for the information. What is the reason to prevent such a usage?

Comment: I have two questions for @DonaldStufft. 1) How do you recommend including dependencies directly from github? Is it `parse_requirements` that is being removed, or just the `process-dependecy-links` option?  I did this and it required me to run `pip install -e . --process-dependency-links` and it kindly let me know I was doing things wrong and that `process-dependency-links` is deprecated

Comment: The ``parse_requirements`` function is being moved to a different location in pip 1.6. Additionally ``--process-dependency-links`` will be completely gone in pip 1.6.

Installing things from github should be done using a requirements file. See https://caremad.io/blog/setup-vs-requirement/

Comment: "No such file requirements.txt" on PIP install. Bad advice.

Comment: This should no longer be the accepted answer, if it ever should have. It's blatantly broken. Even when it worked, it's blatantly unnecessary. Since `pip` defaults to parsing dependencies from `setup.py` in the absence of `requirements.txt`, the [simple answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19081268/2809027) astutely noted by [Tobu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/229753/tobu) below is to **list all dependencies in `setup.py` and remove `requirements.txt`.** For applications requiring both, simply reduce the dependency list in `requirements.txt` to merely the `.` character. _Done._

Comment: I'm downvoting this answer because it no longer works. When I tried it, I got some error about `session` not expected to be a boolean.

Comment: @JasonR.Coombs: Yes, I don't know why someone edited the answer with `session=False` because `session` must be an instance of `pip.download.PipSession`. Maybe a boolean was possible some times ago. I edited my answer anyway because the `.` requirements.txt is neat, even if it's the opposite ;-)

Comment: I believe this is broken as of `pip` 10.

Comment: I can confirm that reducing requirements.txt to the `.` character does in fact work... but it is slow.  When all requirements are already satisfied, `pip install -r requirements.txt` goes from taking 8 seconds with an explicit list to taking 54 seconds with `.`... 7x slower.

Answer (score 386):

On the face of it, it does seem that `requirements.txt` and `setup.py` are silly duplicates, but it's important to understand that while the form is similar, the intended function is very different.

The goal of a package author, when specifying dependencies, is to say "wherever you install this package, these are the other packages you need, in order for this package to work."

In contrast, the deployment author (which may be the same person at a different time) has a different job, in that they say "here's the list of packages that we've gathered together and tested and that I now need to install".

The package author writes for a wide variety of scenarios, because they're putting their work out there to be used in ways they may not know about, and have no way of knowing what packages will be installed alongside their package.  In order to be a good neighbor and avoid dependency version conflicts with other packages, they need to specify as wide a range of dependency versions as can possibly work.  This is what `install_requires` in `setup.py` does.

The deployment author writes for a very different, very specific goal: a single instance of an installed application or service, installed on a particular computer.  In order to precisely control a deployment, and be sure that the right packages are tested and deployed, the deployment author must specify the exact version and source-location of every package to be installed, including dependencies and dependency's dependencies.  With this spec, a deployment can be repeatably applied to several machines, or tested on a test machine, and the deployment author can be confident that the same packages are deployed every time.  This is what a `requirements.txt` does.

So you can see that, while they both look like a big list of packages and versions, these two things have very different jobs.  And it's definitely easy to mix this up and get it wrong!  But the right way to think about this is that `requirements.txt` is an "answer" to the "question" posed by the requirements in all the various `setup.py` package files.  Rather than write it by hand, it's often generated by telling pip to look at all the `setup.py` files in a set of desired packages, find a set of packages that it thinks fits all the requirements, and then, after they're installed, "freeze" that list of packages into a text file (this is where the `pip freeze` name comes from).

So the takeaway:

- `setup.py` should declare the loosest possible dependency versions that are still workable.  Its job is to say what a particular package can work with.
- `requirements.txt` is a deployment manifest that defines an entire installation job, and shouldn't be thought of as tied to any one package.  Its job is to declare an exhaustive list of all the necessary packages to make a deployment work.
- Because these two things have such different content and reasons for existing, it's not feasible to simply copy one into the other.

#### References:

- [install_requires vs Requirements files](https://packaging.python.org/requirements/) from the Python packaging user guide.

Comment: It's still not clear to me why a developer would keep a version-controlled `requirements.txt` along with the source of the package that contains the concrete/frozen requirements for installation or test. Surely `setup.py` can be used for this purpose within the project itself? I can only imagine using such a file for tools used to support *managing* the project (e.g. refactoring, making releases etc.).

Comment: @samBrightman I agree entirely, I don't think library packages _or_ application packages should commit their requirements.txt file to the repository with the code.  I think that should be an artifact generated during the build testing, and then used to document a build manifest and ultimately generate a deployment artifact.

Comment: However, I can accept that not every project has a build and deployment manager, and so it's an ok compromise to store the most recently-generated requirements.txt with an _application_ package's code.

Comment: I'm still not following exactly - which deployment methods would not already express dependencies? You mean if I'm writing code that has no other (natural) way to express Python dependencies, like a script that just wants to grab some utilities and run in a virtualenv, but is not itself a Python package?

Comment: @samBrightman I'm not sure I follow you entirely, let me start over.

I meant that in general, I think setup.py should be the truth of how a python package (be it library or application) declares it's dependencies.  But I also think that setup.py should be as loose as possible regarding the allowed versions of those dependencies.

In an ideal deployment scenario, a build process would take the packages intended for deployment, figure out a workable set of exact package versions for all the various dependencies, and generate a requirements.txt manifest to document a workable build.

Comment: And that deployment manifest should be stored somewhere, either as the actual "product" of the build that's used to actually deploy the release, or simply as documentation.  If I were doing it, it'd go in some S3 bucket or something.

Comment: But not every project out there has a CI build infrastructure in place, or the tooling around deployment artifacts, etc.  In those cases, I can see why, for application packages, someone might commit their generated requirements.txt file back into the git repository, to make it easier for someone else to install their project with a reproducible dependency manifest.

Comment: But I think there's reason, even in that scenario, to keep setup.py separate from requirements.txt.  Setup.py should only declare the _direct_ dependencies of the package it describes, not the flattened set of all the deployment packages.  Also, a package, even an application package, should _never_ pin a unique version for a dependency unless that version is actually the only one that works.  You don't know the installation scenario of everyone that will ever use your application, and it'll cause headaches to demand control over specific versions of packages.

Comment: So you are saying `requirements.txt` is more documentation for the state of the world that produced a given build, even though it is not usually used in the build process itself? That makes sense. However, it looks like several systems rely on duplication: Travis installs some default (old) packages in your virtualenv and says to use `requirements.txt`. If I ask how to ensure dependencies are at latest using `setup.py`, people insist that I should use `requirements.txt`.

Comment: Yea, I mean, I'm not an authority on python packaging, and I don't even think the opinion I've given above is commonly shared.  The entire subject of python packaging is a confusing mess of "you do your thing, I'll do mine", so it's less that there's an official right way to do it that everyone needs to learn, and more that a lot of different people are trying to scrape together a sane model out of what's out there, and developing different opinions in the process.

Comment: The best advice you can get out of any of this is to find a model that works for you, document it well, and make sure everyone you work with understands it.  Think through why you're doing each bit and whether it really makes sense for your use case.  And try to stay as well-read as you can about the current state of building, packaging, and publishing in Python, just in case things get better.  But don't hold your breath.

Comment: Is it fair to say that in contrast to that, for tests_require in setup.py the purpose is the same as for having a requirements-test.txt?

Comment: I've been struggling to help a colleague with this this morning. Is it just me, or does Python itself violate PEP20's "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it" with its packaging? This answer helped me go from completely confused to vaguely understanding the difference, so thanks.

Comment: This seems to be a sledgehammer to deal with a thumb tack. If I want to write a C-executable for my pipe-architecture do-fabble, I can create a library of classes, link them, and move on.   But, with Python, I am left, after reading this, with three options: write scrambled-eggs style code in a single directory, write a single monolithic script (which is actually better than scrambled eggs-style modules), or answer 12 months of programming questions up front with a fully featured architecture before I write a single line of content.  Is there an easy way to halve the cake and eat it too?

Comment: 2/2 ...and so, as a follow up, although I respect the issues you are writing about when your code transitions from the Mediterranean to the Indo-Pacific during a territorial  crisis between the US, India, China and Japan, is there a really good reason not to go with Fredrick Brennan's answer?

Comment: It still seems rather redundant.  Even accounting for your excellent points, still, the only difference that I can see (in most cases) is that `setup.py` should use `>=` and `requirements.txt` should perhaps use `==`.

Comment: Classic quote: 'requirements.txt is an "answer" to the "question" posed by the requirements in all the various setup.py package files' - thank you

Answer (score 149):

It can't take a file handle. The `install_requires` argument can [only be a string or a list of strings](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#new-and-changed-setup-keywords).

You can, of course, read your file in the setup script and pass it as a list of strings to `install_requires`.

```
import os
from setuptools import setup

with open('requirements.txt') as f:
    required = f.read().splitlines()

setup(...
install_requires=required,
...)
```

Comment: Although useful this changes specification of requirements from being declarative to imperative. This makes it impossible for some tools to find out what your requirements are. For instance, PyCharm offers automatic installation of all requirements specified in `install_requires`. However, it does not work if you don't use declarative syntax.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost Perhaps the PyCharm developer should fix their program then. `setup.py` is a program that should be run, not a data file that should be parsed. That doesn't make this answer any worse.

Comment: I'm just pointing out possible problems; this answer is perfectly fine. It's not only PyCharm which has problem with information being "hidden" behind code. This is universal problem and thus there's general move towards declarative specification of metadata in Python packaging.

Comment: Works fine as long as you put `include requirements.txt` into your `MANIFEST.in` or you won't be able to install your library from a source distribution.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but you can at least nowadays configure PyCharm to parse a requirements file at Preferences->Tools->Python integrated tools->Package requirements file

Comment: Best solution from the Pip 6.0 compatibility issue https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2422 - Works for comments and empty lines too.

Comment: Does this work if with a github url in the requirements?

Comment: tox will fail on this model because requirements.txt is not passed to new venv.

Comment: Can confirm that as of at least PyCharm 5.0.3, PyCharm will parse dependencies from `requirements.txt` files by default.

Comment: This is absolutely horrible. Since `pip` defaults to installing all dependencies listed by `setup.py` in the absence of `requirements.txt`, the sane solution is to **list all dependencies in `setup.py` and remove `requirements.txt` entirely.** See also [famousgarkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/681785/famousgarkin) and [Tobu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/229753/tobu)'s explanatory answers.

Comment: This solution works as a charm. It takes even [environment markers](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirement-specifiers) into account!

Comment: When calling "python -m build", we don't seem to be in the local folder => reading the "requirements" won't work, and if I remove "install_requires" completely, it will not take requirements.txt into account either

Answer (score 70):

Requirements files use an expanded pip format, which is only useful if you need to complement your `setup.py` with stronger constraints, for example specifying the exact urls some of the dependencies must come from, or the output of `pip freeze` to freeze the entire package set to known-working versions. If you don't need the extra constraints, use only a `setup.py`. If you feel like you really need to ship a `requirements.txt` anyway, you can make it a single line:

```
.
```

It will be valid and refer exactly to the contents of the `setup.py` that is in the same directory.

Comment: But in this case it would also try to install my app too. What if I don't need it and only want install_requires installed?

Comment: To elaborate on what @ffeast is asking, if requirements exist only in setup.py, is there a way to install the requirements (equivalent of `pip install -r requirements.txt `) without installing the package itself?

Comment: @ffeast @haridsv `-e .` should be enough. Check this page: https://caremad.io/posts/2013/07/setup-vs-requirement/

Comment: @DexD.Hunter it still tries to install the app itself. This is not what we want

Comment: Do you give specific version or a version range to each dependency in setup.py? If a range is given, do you auto-test each possible dependency combination?

Answer (score 42):

While not an exact answer to the question, I recommend Donald Stufft's blog post at https://caremad.io/2013/07/setup-vs-requirement/ for a good take on this problem. I've been using it to great success.

In short, `requirements.txt` is not a `setup.py` alternative, but a deployment complement. Keep an appropriate abstraction of package dependencies in `setup.py`. Set `requirements.txt` or more of 'em to fetch specific versions of package dependencies for development, testing, or production.

E.g. with packages included in the repo under `deps/`:

```
# fetch specific dependencies
--no-index
--find-links deps/

# install package
# NOTE: -e . for editable mode
.
```

pip executes package's `setup.py` and installs the specific versions of dependencies declared in `install_requires`. There's no duplicity and the purpose of both artifacts is preserved.

Comment: This doesn't work when you want to provide a package for others to install via `pip install my-package`. If dependencies for my-package are not listed in my-package/setup.py, they are not installed by `pip install my-package`. I've been unable to determine how to provide a package for others that includes dependencies without explicitly stating them in setup.py. Would love to know if someone has figured out how to keep it DRY while allowing others to install my-package + dependencies without downloading the requirements file and manually calling `pip install -r my-package/requirements.txt`.

Comment: @Malina The package here is perfectly installable without `requirements.txt`. That's the whole point. Updated the question to make things more clear. Also updated obsolete blog post link.

Comment: so when running setup.py it will call requirements.txt for specific versions of the files listed in stup.py?

Comment: It's the other way around @dtracers. requirements.txt points to the package it self, where the setup.py's dependecies could be picked up. So when installing using requirements, it works and when installing through pip, it works too - in both cases using setup.py's dependecies, but also allowing to install more things when using requirements.txt

Answer (score 29):

First, I believe parsing `requirements.txt` to fill the list of dependencies in package metadata is not a good idea. The [`requirements.txt` file and the list of "install dependencies" are two different concepts, they are not interchangeable](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/install-requires-vs-requirements/). It should be the other way around, the list of dependencies in package metadata should be considered as some kind of source of truth, and files such as `requirements.txt` should be generated from there. For example with a tool such as [*`pip-compile`*](https://pypi.org/project/pip-tools/). See the notes at the bottom of this answer.

But everyone has different needs, that lead to different workflows. So with that said... There are 3 possibilities to handle this, depending on where you want your project's package metadata to be written: *`pyproject.toml`*, *`setup.cfg`*, or *`setup.py`*.

---

***Words of caution!***

If you insist on having the list of dependencies in package metadata be read from a `requirements.txt` file then make sure that this `requirements.txt` file is included in the "source distribution" (*sdist*) otherwise installation will fail, for obvious reasons.

These techniques will work only for simple `requirements.txt` files. See [*Requirements parsing* in the documentation page for `pkg_resources`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#requirements-parsing) to get details about what is handled. In short, each line should be a valid [*PEP 508* requirement](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/). [Notations that are really specific to *pip*](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirements-file-format) are not supported and it will cause a failure.

---

***`pyproject.toml`***

```
[project]
# ...
dynamic = ["dependencies"]

[tool.setuptools.dynamic]
# ...
dependencies = requirements.txt
```

---

***`setup.cfg`***

Since setuptools version 62.6 it is possible to write something like this in `setup.cfg`:

```
[options]
install_requires = file: requirements.txt
```

---

***`setup.py`***

It is possible to parse a relatively simple `requirements.txt` file from a *setuptools* `setup.py` script without *pip*. The *setuptools* project already contains necessary tools in its *top level* package `pkg_resources`.

It could more or less look like this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pathlib

import pkg_resources
import setuptools

with pathlib.Path('requirements.txt').open() as requirements_txt:
    install_requires = [
        str(requirement)
        for requirement
        in pkg_resources.parse_requirements(requirements_txt)
    ]

setuptools.setup(
    install_requires=install_requires,
)
```

---

***Notes***:

- https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/install-requires-vs-requirements/
- https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1951#issuecomment-1431345869
- https://caremad.io/posts/2013/07/setup-vs-requirement/
- https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/history.html#v62-6-0
- See also this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59971236

Comment: In case you weren't aware, the reason why many (myself included) have been using `pip`'s parsing and not `pkg_resources`'s since before 2015 are bugs such as https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/470 . This exact one is fixed nowadays, but I'm still a bit scared to use it, since both implementations appear to be developed separately.

Comment: @trevorj Thanks for pointing this, I didn't know. Fact is nowadays it works and getting pip involved seems like a ridiculous idea to me (particularly in this fashion). Have a look at the other answers, most seem like slight variations of the same ill-advised idea, without barely any warning notice. And newcomers might just follow this trend. Hopefully initiatives such as PEP517 and PEP518 will steer the community away from this madness.

Comment: @sinoroc Thanks! Your answer should have the most ups as it's the cleanest. Ideally the user would load requirements.in instead of requirements.txt here. (requirements.in used by pip-tools, may be the precise install_requirements 'truth' we are looking for)

Comment: more or less..?

Comment: `parse_requirements` will fail with a syntax error if the `requirements.txt` file contains options such as `-r`.

Comment: @mhucka Yes, it is known shortcoming, I thought I had mentioned it, but apparently I had only mentioned it in my other (linked) answer. So now I added it and some other updates as well.

Answer (score 24):

Using `parse_requirements` is problematic because the pip API isn't publicly documented and supported.  In pip 1.6, that function is actually moving, so existing uses of it are likely to break.

A more reliable way to eliminate duplication between `setup.py` and `requirements.txt` is to specific your dependencies in `setup.py` and then put `-e .` into your `requirements.txt` file.  Some information from one of the `pip` developers about why that's a better way to go is available here: https://caremad.io/blog/setup-vs-requirement/

Comment: @Tommy Try this: https://caremad.io/2013/07/setup-vs-requirement/ This is the same link as posted in another answer.

Answer (score 19):

Most of the other answers above don't work with the current version of pip's API. Here is the correct* way to do it with the current version of pip (6.0.8 at the time of writing, also worked in 7.1.2. You can check your version with pip -V).

```
from pip.req import parse_requirements
from pip.download import PipSession

install_reqs = parse_requirements(<requirements_path>, session=PipSession())

reqs = [str(ir.req) for ir in install_reqs]

setup(
    ...
    install_requires=reqs
    ....
)
```

* Correct, in that it is the way to use parse_requirements with the current pip. It still probably isn't the best way to do it, since, as posters above said, pip doesn't really maintain an API.

Answer (score 13):

Install the current package in Travis. This avoids the use of a `requirements.txt` file.
For example:

```
language: python
python:
  - "2.7"
  - "2.6"
install:
  - pip install -q -e .
script:
  - python runtests.py
```

Comment: This is by far the best combination of "correct" and "practical".  I'd add that if after the tests pass you can get Travis to generate a requirements.txt with `pip freeze` and export that file somewhere as an artifact (like S3 or something), then you'd have a great way to repeatably install exactly what you tested.

Answer (score 7):

`from pip.req import parse_requirements` did not work for me and I think it's for the blank lines in my requirements.txt, but this function does work

```
def parse_requirements(requirements):
    with open(requirements) as f:
        return [l.strip('\n') for l in f if l.strip('\n') and not l.startswith('#')]

reqs = parse_requirements(<requirements_path>)

setup(
    ...
    install_requires=reqs,
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 6):

The following interface became deprecated in pip 10:

```
from pip.req import parse_requirements
from pip.download import PipSession
```

So I switched it just to simple text parsing:

```
with open('requirements.txt', 'r') as f:
    install_reqs = [
        s for s in [
            line.split('#', 1)[0].strip(' \t\n') for line in f
        ] if s != ''
    ]
```

Answer (score 3):

**BEWARE OF `parse_requirements` BEHAVIOUR!**

Please note that `pip.req.parse_requirements` will change underscores to dashes.  This was enraging me for a few days before I discovered it.  Example demonstrating:

```
from pip.req import parse_requirements  # tested with v.1.4.1

reqs = '''
example_with_underscores
example-with-dashes
'''

with open('requirements.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(reqs)

req_deps = parse_requirements('requirements.txt')
result = [str(ir.req) for ir in req_deps if ir.req is not None]
print result
```

produces

```
['example-with-underscores', 'example-with-dashes']
```

Comment: Use **unsafe_name** to get the underscores version: `[ir.req.unsafe_name for ir in req_deps if ir.req is not None]`

Comment: As pointed out elsewhere, PIP is an application, not a library.  It has no publicly agreed-upon API, and importing it into your code is not a supported use case.  It's not surprising that it has unexpected behavior; its internal functions were never intended to be used this way.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to force your users to install pip, you can emulate its behavior with this:

```
import sys

from os import path as p

try:
    from setuptools import setup, find_packages
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup, find_packages


def read(filename, parent=None):
    parent = (parent or __file__)

    try:
        with open(p.join(p.dirname(parent), filename)) as f:
            return f.read()
    except IOError:
        return ''


def parse_requirements(filename, parent=None):
    parent = (parent or __file__)
    filepath = p.join(p.dirname(parent), filename)
    content = read(filename, parent)

    for line_number, line in enumerate(content.splitlines(), 1):
        candidate = line.strip()

        if candidate.startswith('-r'):
            for item in parse_requirements(candidate[2:].strip(), filepath):
                yield item
        else:
            yield candidate

setup(
...
    install_requires=list(parse_requirements('requirements.txt'))
)
```

Comment: Note that [`distutils`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/distutils/) has been deprecated and is scheduled for removal in Python 3.12.

Answer (score 2):

I created a reusable function for this. It actually parses an entire directory of requirements files and sets them to extras_require.

Latest always available here: https://gist.github.com/akatrevorjay/293c26fefa24a7b812f5

```
import glob
import itertools
import os

# This is getting ridiculous
try:
    from pip._internal.req import parse_requirements
    from pip._internal.network.session import PipSession
except ImportError:
    try:
        from pip._internal.req import parse_requirements
        from pip._internal.download import PipSession
    except ImportError:
        from pip.req import parse_requirements
        from pip.download import PipSession


def setup_requirements(
        patterns=[
            'requirements.txt', 'requirements/*.txt', 'requirements/*.pip'
        ],
        combine=True):
    """
    Parse a glob of requirements and return a dictionary of setup() options.
    Create a dictionary that holds your options to setup() and update it using this.
    Pass that as kwargs into setup(), viola

    Any files that are not a standard option name (ie install, tests, setup) are added to extras_require with their
    basename minus ext. An extra key is added to extras_require: 'all', that contains all distinct reqs combined.

    Keep in mind all literally contains `all` packages in your extras.
    This means if you have conflicting packages across your extras, then you're going to have a bad time.
    (don't use all in these cases.)

    If you're running this for a Docker build, set `combine=True`.
    This will set `install_requires` to all distinct reqs combined.

    Example:

    >>> import setuptools
    >>> _conf = dict(
    ...     name='mainline',
    ...     version='0.0.1',
    ...     description='Mainline',
    ...     author='Trevor Joynson <github@trevor.joynson,io>',
    ...     url='https://trevor.joynson.io',
    ...     namespace_packages=['mainline'],
    ...     packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    ...     zip_safe=False,
    ...     include_package_data=True,
    ... )
    >>> _conf.update(setup_requirements())
    >>> # setuptools.setup(**_conf)

    :param str pattern: Glob pattern to find requirements files
    :param bool combine: Set True to set install_requires to extras_require['all']
    :return dict: Dictionary of parsed setup() options
    """
    session = PipSession()

    # Handle setuptools insanity
    key_map = {
        'requirements': 'install_requires',
        'install': 'install_requires',
        'tests': 'tests_require',
        'setup': 'setup_requires',
    }
    ret = {v: set() for v in key_map.values()}
    extras = ret['extras_require'] = {}
    all_reqs = set()

    files = [glob.glob(pat) for pat in patterns]
    files = itertools.chain(*files)

    for full_fn in files:
        # Parse
        reqs = {
            str(r.req)
            for r in parse_requirements(full_fn, session=session)
            # Must match env marker, eg:
            #   yarl ; python_version >= '3.0'
            if r.match_markers()
        }
        all_reqs.update(reqs)

        # Add in the right section
        fn = os.path.basename(full_fn)
        barefn, _ = os.path.splitext(fn)
        key = key_map.get(barefn)

        if key:
            ret[key].update(reqs)
            extras[key] = reqs

        extras[barefn] = reqs

    if 'all' not in extras:
        extras['all'] = list(all_reqs)

    if combine:
        extras['install'] = ret['install_requires']
        ret['install_requires'] = list(all_reqs)

    def _listify(dikt):
        ret = {}

        for k, v in dikt.items():
            if isinstance(v, set):
                v = list(v)
            elif isinstance(v, dict):
                v = _listify(v)
            ret[k] = v

        return ret

    ret = _listify(ret)

    return ret


__all__ = ['setup_requirements']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    reqs = setup_requirements()
    print(reqs)
```

Comment: very nice! even handles recursive requirements with latest pip :)

Comment: @amohr Thanks! I recently updated it for an even later pip, I'm unsure why they they're acting the way they are, by moving things to `pip._internal`.. If you don't provide a usable external API, then you shouldn't break all those that are using all that you provide.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution...

```
def gather_requirements(top_path=None):
    """Captures requirements from repo.

    Expected file format is: requirements[-_]<optional-extras>.txt

    For example:

        pip install -e .[foo]

    Would require:

        requirements-foo.txt

        or

        requirements_foo.txt

    """
    from pip.download import PipSession
    from pip.req import parse_requirements
    import re

    session = PipSession()
    top_path = top_path or os.path.realpath(os.getcwd())
    extras = {}
    for filepath in tree(top_path):
        filename = os.path.basename(filepath)
        basename, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
        if ext == '.txt' and basename.startswith('requirements'):
            if filename == 'requirements.txt':
                extra_name = 'requirements'
            else:
                _, extra_name = re.split(r'[-_]', basename, 1)
            if extra_name:
                reqs = [str(ir.req) for ir in parse_requirements(filepath, session=session)]
                extras.setdefault(extra_name, []).extend(reqs)
    all_reqs = set()
    for key, values in extras.items():
        all_reqs.update(values)
    extras['all'] = list(all_reqs)
    return extras
```

and then to use...

```
reqs = gather_requirements()
install_reqs = reqs.pop('requirements', [])
test_reqs = reqs.pop('test', [])
...
setup(
    ...
    'install_requires': install_reqs,
    'test_requires': test_reqs,
    'extras_require': reqs,
    ...
)
```

Comment: where does `tree` come from?

Comment: @FrancescoBoi if you forgive me a little for not presenting a fully working solution...  tree is really just a scan of the local file system (very similar to a "tree" command in linux).  Also, my solution above may not work entirely at this point because pip is constantly being updated and I used pip internals.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround that works for me

**WARNING:** Only use when you are not using `setup.cfg` already !!! This will overwrite `setup.cfg`

1. Keep `requirements.txt` and `requirements-dev.txt` at same level as `setup.py`
2. Remove these lines from `setup.py`

   ```py
   install_requires=...
   extras_require=...
   ```
3. Add this to `setup.py` to create `setup.cfg` and load requirements from files -  `requirements.txt` and `requirements-dev.txt`

   ```py
   # Read the dependencies from requirements.txt
   try:
       with open("requirements.txt", "r", encoding="utf8") as f:
           requirements = f.read().splitlines()
       requirements = [
           f"\t{req.strip()}\n" for req in requirements if req.strip()[0] != "#"
       ]
   except FileNotFoundError:
       requirements = []
   finally:
       if requirements:
           requirements = ["[options]\n", "install_requires =\n"] + requirements
           with open("setup.cfg", "w", encoding="utf8") as cfg:
               cfg.writelines(requirements)

   # Read the extra dependencies from requirements_extra.txt
   try:
       with open("requirements-dev.txt", "r", encoding="utf8") as f:
           dev_requirements = f.read().splitlines()
       dev_requirements = [
           f"\t{req.strip()}\n" for req in dev_requirements if req.strip()[0] != "#"
       ]
   except FileNotFoundError:
       dev_requirements = []
   finally:
       if dev_requirements:
           dev_requirements = [
               "\n[options.extras_require]\n",
               "dev =\n",
           ] + dev_requirements
           with open("setup.cfg", "a", encoding="utf8") as cfg:
               cfg.writelines(dev_requirements)
   ```

`setup.cfg` should look like this after you run `python setup.py sdist`

```
[options]
install_requires =
   package_1
   ...

[options.extras_require]
dev =
    package_2
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Cross posting my answer from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57191701/3728233) for another simple, pip version proof solution.

```
try:  # for pip >= 10
    from pip._internal.req import parse_requirements
    from pip._internal.download import PipSession
except ImportError:  # for pip <= 9.0.3
    from pip.req import parse_requirements
    from pip.download import PipSession

requirements = parse_requirements(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'requirements.txt'), session=PipSession())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup(
        ...
        install_requires=[str(requirement.req) for requirement in requirements],
        ...
    )
```

Then just throw in all your requirements under `requirements.txt` under project root directory.

Answer (score -2):

Yet another `parse_requirements` hack that also parses environment markers into `extras_require`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pip.req import parse_requirements

requirements = []
extras = defaultdict(list)
for r in parse_requirements('requirements.txt', session='hack'):
    if r.markers:
        extras[':' + str(r.markers)].append(str(r.req))
    else:
        requirements.append(str(r.req))

setup(
    ...,
    install_requires=requirements,
    extras_require=extras
)
```

It should support both sdist and binary dists.

As stated by others, `parse_requirements` has several shortcomings, so this is not what you should do on public projects, but it may suffice for internal/personal projects.

Comment: pip 20.1 changed their API and markers are not available via `parse_requirements()` anymore, so this now fails.

Answer (score -2):

I did this:

```
import re

def requirements(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        ll = f.read().splitlines()
    d = {}
    for l in ll:
        k, v = re.split(r'==|>=', l)
        d[k] = v
    return d

def packageInfo():
    try:
        from pip._internal.operations import freeze
    except ImportError:
        from pip.operations import freeze

    d = {}
    for kv in freeze.freeze():
        k, v = re.split(r'==|>=', kv)
        d[k] = v
    return d

req = getpackver('requirements.txt')
pkginfo = packageInfo()

for k, v in req.items():
    print(f'{k:<16}: {v:<6} -> {pkginfo[k]}')
```

Answer (score -4):

Here is a complete hack (tested with `pip 9.0.1`) based on [Romain's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16624700/239247) that parses `requirements.txt` and filters it according to current [environment markers](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirement-specifiers):

```
from pip.req import parse_requirements

requirements = []
for r in parse_requirements('requirements.txt', session='hack'):
    # check markers, such as
    #
    #     rope_py3k    ; python_version >= '3.0'
    #
    if r.match_markers():
        requirements.append(str(r.req))

print(requirements)
```

Comment: This is only partially true. If you call `r.match_markers()` you're actually evaluating the markers, which is correct thing to do for a sdist. However, if you're building a binary dist (e.g. wheel), the package would only list those libraries that matched *your* build-time environment.

Comment: @TuukkaMustonen, so where to find this `wheel environment` (if it is the thing person tries to do) to evaluate markers against it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/41172125/165629 that should also support `bdist_wheel`. It doesn't evaluate markers, it just adds them to `extras_require`.