# Automatically read requirements.txt in fabric or deploy

Tags: amazon-ec2, flask, pip, fabric, distribute

I have a flask app where I'm trying to automate deployment to EC2.

Not a big deal, but is there a setting in either Fabric or Distribute that reads the requirements.txt file directly for the setup.py, so I don't have to spell everything out in the setup(install_requires=[]) list, rather than writing a file reader for my requirements.txt?  If not, do people have recommendations or suggestions on auto-deployment and with pip?

I'm reviewing from [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/fabric/) and [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/distribute/#distribute-deployment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Not a big deal, but is there a setting in either Fabric or Distribute
>   that reads the requirements.txt file directly for the setup.py, so I
>   don't have to spell everything out in the setup(install_requires=[])
>   list, rather than writing a file reader for my requirements.txt?

You might still want to checkout frb's answer to the duplicate question [How can I reference requirements.txt for the install_requires kwarg in setuptools.setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14399775/45773), which provides a straight forward two line solution for *writing a file reader*.

If you really want to avoid this, you could alternatively add the common `pip install -r requirements.txt`to your `fabfile.py`, e.g.:

```
# ...
# create a place where we can unzip the tarball, then enter
# that directory and unzip it
run('mkdir /tmp/yourapplication')
with cd('/tmp/yourapplication'):
    run('tar xzf /tmp/yourapplication.tar.gz')
    # now install the requirements with our virtual environment's
    # pip installer
    run('/var/www/yourapplication/env/scripts/pip install -r requirements.txt')
    # now setup the package with our virtual environment's
    # python interpreter
    run('/var/www/yourapplication/env/bin/python setup.py install')
```

Comment: Yeah, it's something that was so simple it wasn't a problem to write, but was also simple enough I equally assumed good python package writers may have just added an option somewhere.  Thanks!

Comment: @Mittenchops - Agreed, the non unified state of Python's various setup procedures/tools is actually violating [PEP 20](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), unfortunately: _"There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way"_  to specify (and use) package/setup metadata, which obviously includes dependencies ...