# setup.py doesn't see my requirements.txt

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

Try

```
pip install tornado-botocore
```

it says:

```
pip.exceptions.InstallationError: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
```

Code inside setup.py:

```
REQUIREMETS = [str(r.req) for r in parse_requirements('requirements.txt')]


setup(
    ...
    package_data={'': ['requirements.txt']},
    install_requires=REQUIREMETS,
)
```

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I reference requirements.txt for the install\_requires kwarg in setuptools' setup.py file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399534/how-can-i-reference-requirements-txt-for-the-install-requires-kwarg-in-setuptool)

Comment: @RafaelBarros, yes, I am doing the same, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Can you share the folder structure? the exception is saying it can't find the `requirements.txt` file, is it on the same directory as setup.py?

Comment: @RafaelBarros, yes, of course, see [tornado-botocore](https://github.com/nanvel/tornado-botocore)

Comment: @RafaelBarros, resolved by adding `include requirements.txt` into Manifest.in.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add `requirements.txt` to `MANIFEST.in`.