# pip won't install my package's dependencies

Tags: python, git, pip, setup.py

I'm using `pip install git+http://github.com/myuser/myrepo.git#egg=myrepo` (in a virtualenv of course) to install a package that I'm working on, and my git repo has a `requirements.txt`, but pip won't install it's dependencies. Is there a way to make this work similarly to when I use pip with a package from PyPI, so that my dependences will be installed automatically?

Comment: You can use `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: pip doesn't implicitly process any requirements.txt. however, if you'll add deps into setup.py - they will be installed even when installing package from git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from my understanding pip only installs dependencies specified in the setup.py.

however if you prefer to use requirements to keep all dependencies, you may include requirements in setup.py by:

```
import os
from setuptools import setup
with open('requirements.txt') as f:
required = f.read().splitlines()

setup(...
    install_requires=required,
...)
```

code copied from: [Reference requirements.txt for the install_requires kwarg in setuptools setup.py file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399534/how-can-i-reference-requirements-txt-for-the-install-requires-kwarg-in-setuptool)