# Build dependencies automatically with setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools

In my package `setup.py` I have

```
setup(
    ...
    requires=['enum', 'hashlib', ...]
)
```

I have to edit the `requires` field manually if I add a dependency in my package and the thing is: I often forget to do that.

Is there an option that can automatically look for imported packages that are not part of the current package?

Comment: Why don't you load and parse the `requirements.txt`?

Comment: I am just discovering `requirements.txt`. Does `setuptool` populate this file automatically?

Comment: Not afaik. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399534/how-can-i-reference-requirements-txt-for-the-install-requires-kwarg-in-setuptool) has a way to load the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is quite old now and I'm sure you managed to find a way around this problem, but anyway. Just to have an answer for this question: I do it the same way as suggested in the comment by just parsing the `requirements.txt`. Here is the code of one of my packages:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
  name="my_package",
  version="1.0.0",
  description="Just a package",

  ...

  # this will return every module listed in requirements.txt
  install_requires=[line.strip() for line in open("requirements.txt", "r").readlines()],

)
```

I hope this resolves the question :)

Comment: In your case you are moving the problem somewhere else. There I still have to manually maintain the list of requirements.txt up to date...

Comment: Although there are some scanners that parse your project directory for lines starting with `import ...` and `from ...`, I have no real trust in them since they often mess up things and do the requirements.txt myself. If you are usind PyCharm or a similar IDE, modules which are not im requirements.txt are highlighted in your code. (a very handy feature if you ask me...)