# Structuring setup.py and requirements.txt so that pip installs properly

Tags: python, django, setup.py

I'm trying to write a python package that can be installed from PyPI and am having trouble getting my head around how exactly to structure `setup.py` and `requirements.txt` properly.

I know that they have different semantics and different purposes with `setup.py` defining whats needed, and `requirements.txt` given exact versions. I also know that you [shouldn't read `requirements.txt` into `setup.py`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399534/how-can-i-reference-requirements-txt-for-the-install-requires-kwarg-in-setuptool).

So what I need to know is how to structure `setup.py` and `requirements.txt` so that when my package is installed from PyPI the reight requirements are installed.

In my example, I need `django-haystack` (the latest version is `2.5.1`), but my code is only compatible with `django-haystack` version `2.5.0`, so my `setup.py` and `requirements.txt` are as shown below:

`setup.py`:

```
setup(
    name='my_package',
    install_requires = [
        'django-haystack',
    ],
)
```

`requirements.txt`:

```
django-haystack==2.5.0
```

How can I structure my setup code so that when this is installed, `django-haystack==2.5.0` is installed not the latest?

Answer (score 2):

First, a warning: specify explicit version requirements in a `setup.py` file without a range will guarantee frustration for end-users in the future.

You can simply do it like so in the `setup.py` file.

```
setup(
    name='my_package',
    install_requires=[
        'django-haystack==2.5.0',
    ],
)
```

However, if another user wish to  use another package that requires `django-haystack` latest version, they won't be able to install your package as defined due to version conflict issues.  Of course, if the package at hand is so flaky that it can't even attempt to use semantic versioning then there isn't really much can be done.

Now if all you are after is a reproducible build, the `requirements.txt` method can be used for explicit version requirements for *all* packages within your environment, which is out of band from the typical package dependency structure, however it won't suffer from the potentially crippling lockdown from conflicting requirements that aren't actually in conflict.  [`zc.buildout`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.buildout/2.5.3) is an alternative, but much more heavier but it does a lot more than just Python.

Comment: Part of the reason for version pinning is I'm trying to use pyup.io to help both test my dependencies and keep them up to date.

Comment: I recently learned about pyup.io and am wondering what is its use case? Shouldn't my tests tell me where things break when I update my virtualenv? I guess using step by step updates would make it more clear for big projects?