# How can do we include all the dependencies of sub module while packaging in python?

Tags: python, setuptools, python-wheel, python-packaging

Basically i have the project below :

```
my_pkg
 __init__.py
 \module1
    __init__.py
    scrip1.py
    script2.py
    requirement.txt
 \module2
    _script1.py
    _script2.py
    requirement.txt
 setup.py
 LICENSE
 README.md
```

I am trying to include the requirement.txt files with the packaging of my library **my_pkg**

The requirement.txt in module1 folder contains:
`request`

the requirement.txt in module2 folder contains:
`pdfkit`

This is my setup.py file :

```
import setuptools
from setuptools import setup

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setup(
    name="im_pkg",
    version="0.0.1",
    author="John Doe",
    description="Shared Python library",
    long_description=long_description,
    license="MIT",
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    install_requires=["requests","pdfkit"],
    python_requires='>=3.6'
)
```

I would like to read my requirement.txt of my subfolder dynamically without having to put it manually in  the **install_requires=** section

Comment: The answer is to throw the `requirements.txt` files away. For a library, they serve no purpose. The `install_requires` field in your `setup.py` is the source of truth for project dependencies, and you got that covered already.

Comment: To be fair, there do exist packaging tools that can bundle `requirements.txt`s and essentially build a `setup.py` or `setup.cfg` for you, most popularly [`pbr`](https://pypi.org/project/pbr/). But they usually expect only a single requirement file, and as I said above, are a little misguided in their approach. See also [this post](https://caremad.io/posts/2013/07/setup-vs-requirement/) from one of the main authors of the python packaging toolchain for some further info.

Answer (score 0):

You should only list primary dependencies alongwith their versions so that it doesn't break. Don't list stuff that was used for developing such as `yapf`, `black`, `pytest`, `flake8` etc. Keep the requirements as minimal as possible.

However, if you don't want to that, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399534/reference-requirements-txt-for-the-install-requires-kwarg-in-setuptools-setup-py) is the answer you are looking for.

Example:

```
    install_requires=[
        "graphene==2.1.8",
        "graphene-django==2.5.0",
        "graphql-core==2.2.1",
        "psycopg2==2.8.3"
    ],
```