# Why does installing `install_requires` from setup.py using a dot "." in the requirements.txt fail in Dockerfile?

Tags: python, docker, pip, setup.py

I am trying to use the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16624700/6662425)

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8

COPY requirements.txt setup.py /tmp/
RUN pip3 install -r /tmp/requirements.txt \
    && rm /tmp/*
```

this fails with:

```sh
Step 1/7 : FROM python:3.8
 ---> 79cc46abd78d
Step 2/7 : COPY requirements.txt setup.py /tmp/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a50a0a8ecb06
Step 3/7 : RUN pip3 install -r /tmp/requirements.txt     && rm /tmp/*
 ---> Running in c7d29bd8f23c
ERROR: Directory '.' is not installable. Neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml'
 found.
```

I also tried commenting out the `RUN` command, entering the container and running
`pip3 install -r /tmp/requirements.txt` manually. This worked without error.

I have no idea what might be the issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:

the dot `.` is not relative to the `requirements.txt` but rather to the current working directory. The reason it worked when I did it manually is, that I also mounted my workspace into a devcontainer and had my working directory in this workspace which also contained the `setup.py`

The solution is thus to do something like this:

```
WORKDIR /tmp
COPY requirements.txt setup.py ./
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt \
    && rm /tmp/*
```