# Add requirements.txt automatically to setup.py to install them when installing a package

Tags: python, package, setup.py, requirements.txt

I am making a package out of a python app I have, I want that when I install this package in another app the dependencies of the package got installed automatically.
The dependencies in the original package are in requirements.txt.

How can I do that?

I got setup.py and inside setup() I added install_requires= and a list of the dependencies, but I want that whenever I make it a tar.gz package the dependencies from requirements.txt got automatically in there as a list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference requirements.txt for the install\_requires kwarg in setuptools setup.py file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399534/reference-requirements-txt-for-the-install-requires-kwarg-in-setuptools-setup-py)