# installing multiple python packages by single python file

Tags: python, pip, installation, libraries, setup.py

How to make a python file, which installs the mentioned python packages, on running that python file in console instead of installing packages one by one as we do by using pip
I am also confused with setup.py is it same 
and if it is how to do
please help

Comment: As you mentioned, you can use pip and create `requirement.txt` file to install required packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make one text file which has your name of package requirements. Like this is **requirement.txt**

```
requests==2.7.0
selenium==3.4.3
Flask==0.10.1
retrying==1.3.3
```

then you can run it like

```
pip install -r requirement.txt
```

Note: Place this `txt` file to at where the `pip` is.

And for how this differs from the `setup.py` you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43658870/requirements-txt-vs-setup-py)

Comment: is it a python file?

Comment: No it's a text file.

Comment: so what was the question?