# Installing multiple packages single time in Python 3.8

Tags: python-3.x, package

I need to install below packages in Python 3.8.
How to do single time?
Thanks in advance.

I try with this. But not working.
[installing multiple python packages by single python file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47941418/installing-multiple-python-packages-by-single-python-file)

For example I want to install below:

```
numpy=1.13.1
oauth2client=4.1.2
oauthlib=2.0.2
olefile=0.44
optionaldict=0.1.1
pandas=0.24.1
pbr=4.0.3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For installing multiple packages on the command line, just pass them after a space

```
pip install numpy oauth2client oauthlib olefile ....
```

cheers

Comment: or paste the following library names in txt file and import it in pip like ```pip install -r requirements.txt```

Answer (score 1):

> - create a file named `requirements.txt` in your project.
> - Activate your virtual environment.
> - upgrade the pip.
> - `pip install -r requirements.txt`