# Installing multiple libraries 'permanently' on Databricks' cluster

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

There are multiple libraries I work with and I currently run in each notebook command `pip install x y z` to use them. As I do so in multiple notebooks, this is not the most convenient way and it makes sense for the libraries to be automatically installed when cluster is starting. This is possible by specifying a list of preinstalled ones in cluster configuration.

However, when I go to the configuration and select PyPi only one library can be selected at once. So for each single library I need to individually open selection screen, write the name, save and then do the same with the rest. Is there a way to provide a list like with pip `pandas==xx numpy==xx ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a text file to list your package requirements. I have created **Sparklibs.txt** with the following content:

```
pandas==1.3.3
numpy==1.21.2
requests==2.7.0
selenium==3.4.3
Flask==0.10.1
retrying==1.3.3
```

In Sparklibs.txt, each package requirement should be listed on a new line, specifying the package name and version.

This file can then be used with the `pip install -r Sparklibs.txt` command to install all the listed packages and their dependencies.

```
%pip install -r /dbfs/FileStore/tables/Sparklibs.txt
```

**Results:**

[image]

[image]

**Reference:** [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47941418/installing-multiple-python-packages-by-single-python-file) link

As you memtioned that you want the libraries automatically installed components for all notebooks

You can install libraries on cluster:

Go to the Cluster Page:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have tried  the other approach

```
#!/bin/bash
pip install pandas==1.3.3
pip install numpy==1.21.2
```

I used the above and Saved the following script as **install_dependencies.sh**

I have uploaded to install_dependencies.sh to the Workspace under my username

Then in the Cluster configuration page under the advance settings:

[image]

Restarted the Cluster

Results:

[image]

Comment: Tried this previously. This installs libraries only in the notebook where the 'pip' is run. The goal is to add libraries as automatically installed components for all notebooks

Comment: Ok let me update the solution for installing the libraries on the cluster.

Comment: Thank you for replying, however, like I originally mentioned in my question this was tested as well and it requires to individually open selection screen and provide details for each single library I need to install. The goal is to install everything together

Comment: @Pengshe I have added the solution install the library using the init script can you check and let me know if it help you?

Comment: Yes, the final part is what I was searching for, thanks

Answer (score 1):

> However....only one library can be selected at once. Is there a way to provide a list... ?

- You can not do this using WebUI.
- Easiest is to use [databricks cli](https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/cli/tutorial.html)'s [libraries command](https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/libraries/install) for an existing cluster (*or [create job command](https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/jobs/create#job_clusters) and specify appropriate params for your job cluster*)
- Can use the REST API itself, same links as above, using CURL or something.
- Could also [use terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs) to do this if you want a full CI/CD automation.

E.g. following will install two python packages and one maven package (from pypi and maven central respectively) to an existing cluster with cluster id `1234-567890-abcdefghi` (you can get cluster id from [cluster configuration WebUI](https://docs.databricks.com/en/compute/clusters-manage.html#view-a-cluster-configuration-as-a-json-file) URL or JSON).

```bash
$ databricks libraries install --json '{
  "cluster_id": "1234-567890-abcdefghi",
  "libraries": [
    {"pypi": {"package": "openpyxl==3.1.2"}},
    {"pypi": {"package": "apache-airflow 2.8.2"}},
    {"maven": {"coordinates": "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1"}}
  ]
}'
```

---

[Syntax for `libraries` tag](https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/libraries/install):

```json
{
  "cluster_id": "string",
  "libraries": [
    {
      "jar": "string",
      "egg": "string",
      "pypi": {
        "package": "string",
        "repo": "string"
      },
      "maven": {
        "coordinates": "string",
        "repo": "string",
        "exclusions": [
          "string"
        ]
      },
      "cran": {
        "package": "string",
        "repo": "string"
      },
      "whl": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```