# github python action failing on numpy

Tags: python-3.x, github-actions

I have following `deploy.yaml` file

```
name: The fancy name
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  deploy:
    name: deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Setup Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: '3.x'
          architecture: 'x64'
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install -r requirements.txt
      - name: Tests
        run: python3 -m pytest
```

here is what i have in `requirements.txt` file

```
apache-beam==2.18.0
protobuf==3.11.2
pytest==5.3.5
Faker==4.0.0
```

But github action is failing with following errors

```
/Python/3.8.1/x64/lib/python3.8/config-3.8-x86_64-linux-gnu
  -- Looking for python3.8
  -- Found Python lib /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.1/x64/lib/libpython3.8.so
  -- Found PythonLibs: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.1/x64/lib/libpython3.8.so
  CMake Error at cmake_modules/FindNumPy.cmake:62 (message):
    NumPy import failure:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
```

What should be the path forward here?

```
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    CMakeLists.txt:189 (find_package)
```

Comment: According to your `requirements.txt` file, you are not installing NumPy with your other dependencies. Add `numpy==1.18.2` to `requirements.txt` to install NumPy (latest version at time of writing).

There could also be a problem with the virtual environment (or lack thereof) if you are using one locally but not in your GitHub Actions workflow.

Comment: My project wasn't dependent on `numpy` so the problem wasn't `numpy` by itsel. The problem was `python` version. I changed the version to `3.6` and it worked perfeclty.

Comment: I had specified my requirements only in `setup.py`, adding a `requirements.txt` with only `.` inside as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/49684835/1870254 solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if anyone else ran into this issue and needs an answer. For me specifying specific python version worked. I don't remember exactly but i had to put either `3.6` or `3.7` for python.

Just to be clear, my project didn't require numpy, it was some other dependency which was compatible with python 3.8 and pulled numpy in the code.