# Upgrading a project from buildout to pip?

Tags: python, pip, packaging

I am trying to upgrade a Pyramid project to Python 3. I am also exploring various on how to improve the build system so that is more modern.

Currently we are using Python's `buildout` to setup an instance. The approach is simple:

1. All the required `eggs` (including `app` - which is my package) are stored in a buildout configuration file with their **exact** versions specified.
2. Run buildout to get the exact `eggs` (including third party stuff) from  a local package server.
3. Run the instance using `./bin/pserve config.ini`.

For my new `app` source code that has Python 3 changes, I am trying to get rid of everything and just use `pip` instead. This is what I have done now (in a docker container):

```
git clone git@github.com/org/app.git
cd project
# Our internal components are fetched using the `git` directive inside `requirements.txt`.
pip install -r requirements.txt  # Mostly from PyPi.
pip install .
```

It works, but is this the correct way to deploy an application for deployment?

Will I be able to convert the entire installation to a simple: `pip install app` and run it using `pserve config.ini` if I do the following:

1. Upload the latest `app` egg to my package server.
2. Sync setup.py and requirements.txt so that Python to do `pip install -r requirements.txt` (or its equivalent) internally?
3. `pip install app`.
4. Copy `config.ini` to the machine where I am going to install.
5. Run `pserver config.ini`

I wanted to know if the above approach can be made to work before proceeding with the egg creation, mocking a simple package server etc. I am not sure if I can really do `pip install` for a web application; and I think `requirements.txt` has some significance in this case.

I haven't explored `wheels` yet, but if the above works, I will try that as well.

Since I am really new to packaging, would appreciate if I can some suggestions to modernize by build using the latest tools.

---

After reading some of the links like [requirements.txt vs setup.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43658870/requirements-txt-vs-setup-py/49684835), I think `requirements.txt` is needed for Web Apps especially if you want a **consistent** behaviour for deployment purposes. A project or an application seems to be different than a library where `pip install suffices`.

If that is the case, I think the ideal way is to do `pip install -r requirements.txt` and then `pip install app` from a local package server without git cloning?

Resources: [install_requires vs requirements files](https://packaging.python.org/discussions/install-requires-vs-requirements/)

Comment: So... if you read this link, you know that if you run your app like `./bin/pserve config.ini` then you should use `requirements.txt`, right?

Comment: @sanyash, I am trying to run it like `pserver config.ini`; `bin/pserve` is a buildout mechanism that almost does the same thing but not quite same AFAIK.

Comment: Anyway, you are doing `run app` in some sense, not `import app` in Python code. Thus said, using `pip install -r requirements.txt` in your dockerfile looks perfectly fine.

Comment: @sanyash Yeah, I wasn't really clear about what is suitable where -- the more I understand it, `pip install -r requirements` approach seems to be correct for a project compared to a library. I never knew the difference!